# for loop with multiple commands

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have multiple filenames in `files.txt`. I want to run three scripts on each file. I my suggestion correct?

files.txt:

```
SRR13143.sra
SRR44234.sra
SRR23424.sra
```

my try:

```
for FILE in "file.txt";
do
prefetch --max-size 300G $FILE
fastq-dump --gzip --split-3 $FILE
rm $FILE;
done
```

Comment: You're not reading filenames from `file.txt`, you're just looping over the name `file.txt` literally.

Comment: BTW, you should always quote variables unless you have a good reason not to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a `while` loop instead.

```
while IFS= read -r FILE; do
  prefetch --max-size 300G "$FILE"
  fastq-dump --gzip --split-3 "$FILE"
  rm "$FILE"
done < file.txt
```

Comment: Maybe as a finishing touch, prefer lower case for your private variable.

Comment: Might want to redirect the commands in the loop `</dev/null` if we don't know them not to consume stdin, just out of caution. Or put `file.txt` on an alternate fd.

Comment: If one of the script adds a extenstion to the output, for instance SRR13143.sra.gz, could I write: "$FILE".gz ??